# Use ggplot2 to make a scatterplot with categorical axes

Tags: r, ggplot2, regression, scatter-plot

I have a dataset that looks something like this:

```
region    expression    species/gene
reg1      4             humanA
reg1      5             humanB
reg1      4             ratA
reg1      6             ratB
reg2      3             humanA
reg2      5             humanB
reg2      8             ratA
reg2      2             ratB
```

In which I want to plot regions1-n along the x-axis and expression values on the y-axis, color-coded by the value of species/gene. I also want to plot trendlines through each species/gene group and show r-values in the margin. Ideally I'd use something of the format

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=xvar, y=yvar)) +
geom_point(shape=1) +    
geom_smooth(method=lm) +
geom_point(shape=19, alpha=1/4)
```

but I'm too noobly to figure out how to entwine this with my data. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Try this for example :

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dat,aes(x=region,y=expression,
   group=species.gene,color=species.gene)) + 
  geom_line()
```

[image]